# delay mouseenter event and raise event if mouse inside the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I use this tab view that developed base on jQuery:

https://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/001_Tabbed/site/jQuery.html#

I change the code that tabs change by `mouseenter` event. and I want to delay execution of the `mouseenter` event so if mouse enter the elemnt and remain there for portion of time `mouseenter` executes else (if mouse go outside in time less that that portion of time) `mouseenter` does not execute.I write this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.tab').on('mouseenter', function () {
            var thisElement = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".active").removeClass("active");
                thisElement.addClass("active");
                $(".content").slideUp();
                var content_show = thisElement.attr("title");
                $("#" + content_show).slideDown();
            }, 300);
        });
    });
```

but if I bring mouse out of element `mouseenter` excecutes.How to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to store the timeout handle and cancel it on `mouseleave`:

```
var timeout; 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.tab').on('mouseenter', function () {
        var thisElement = $(this);

        if (timeout != null) { clearTimeout(timeout); }

        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            thisElement.addClass("active");
            $(".content").slideUp();
            var content_show = thisElement.attr("title");
            $("#" + content_show).slideDown();
        }, 300);
    });

    $('a.tab').on('mouseleave', function () {
        if (timeout != null) { 
           clearTimeout(timeout); 

           timeout = null;
        }
    });
});
```