# Unwanted mouse events when scrolling content by javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating listbox-like widget with scrollable content (overflow:scroll).
Any item could be selected by mouse hover or by keyboard (using up/down arrows).

The problem is:

when selecting item by keyboard, newly selected item must be scrolled into view. Due to that scroll, items are moved under mouse cursor and this brings unwanted mouse events.

How to prevent an item from getting mouse events when scrolling via scrollIntoView (or similar)?

```js
var VK_DOWN = 40;


$('#scrollable div').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#scrollable div').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});




$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == VK_DOWN) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //select next item
    var selected = $('div.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected = selected.next().addClass('selected');

    //scroll to selected item (if necessary)
    if (selected.position().top + 20 > 300) {
      selected[0].scrollIntoView(false);
    }


  } //vk_down
});
```

```css
#scrollable {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#scrollable div {
  background: lightgray;
  border-bottom:2px solid white;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="scrollable">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11 click this item, then press "down arrow" few times.</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
  <div>32</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>35</div>
  <div>36</div>
  <div>37</div>
  <div>38</div>
  <div>39</div>
  <div>40</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sck0cbjn/1/

My first thought was to set flag "ItsMeScrolling" just before scrollIntoView() (remove flag after scroll), and ignore mouse event each time the flag is set.
This didn't work - at the time of mouse event, the flag was never set.

Comment: Maybe look at this, this question/answer is setting a timeout. Ultimately as soon as they go to move their mouse again, it's going to hover over whatever is in view, but with the timeout you can at least scroll through multiple entries without having the row freak out on you. Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084848/delay-mouseenter-event-and-raise-event-if-mouse-inside-the-element

Comment: Thanks but I don't like to use tiemouts in such cases - it's a makeshift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is extremely simple:

If the mouse event were intended, mouse cursor would move.
So if we get an event without cursor movement, it has to be caused by scrolling.

http://jsfiddle.net/sck0cbjn/7/

```js
var VK_DOWN = 40;
var lastCursorPos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};


$('#scrollable div').mousemove(function(e) {
  var currentCursorPos = {
    x: e.screenX,
    y: e.screenY
  };

  if (currentCursorPos.x == lastCursorPos.x &&
    currentCursorPos.y == lastCursorPos.y) {
    console.log("cursor didn't move so this event was not intended.");
    return;
  }
  lastCursorPos = {
    x: e.screenX,
    y: e.screenY
  };

  $('#scrollable div').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#scrollable div').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
  lastCursorPos = {
    x: e.screenX,
    y: e.screenY
  };
});




$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.which == VK_DOWN) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //select next item
    var selected = $('div.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected = selected.next().addClass('selected');

    //scroll to selected item (if necessary)
    if (selected.position().top + 20 > 300) {
      selected[0].scrollIntoView(false);
    }

  } //vk_down
});
```

```css
#scrollable {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#scrollable div {
  background: lightgray;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}
.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="scrollable">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11 click this item, then press "down arrow" few times.</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div>17</div>
  <div>18</div>
  <div>19</div>
  <div>20</div>
  <div>21</div>
  <div>22</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
  <div>26</div>
  <div>27</div>
  <div>28</div>
  <div>29</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>31</div>
  <div>32</div>
  <div>33</div>
  <div>34</div>
  <div>35</div>
  <div>36</div>
  <div>37</div>
  <div>38</div>
  <div>39</div>
  <div>40</div>
</div>
```

**Beware of that:**
When moving cursor from one element to another (without gap between) you will get:
mouseleave and then mouseenter events with **the same coords!**